# Code first with stored procedure output column mapping when spaces in output column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

What is the best way to handle this situation. I am working with legacy stored procedures and one of the stored procedures uses code like this

```
select c.Name AS 'Company Name' ...
```

I want to execute the stored procedure and have it map to my model correctly but what should I name the variable if the returned column has a space in it? Do I use the actual DB table column name as a fallback?

Example:

```
SqlQuery<MyCustomModel>("exec MyStoredProcedure").ToList<MyCustomModel>();
```

My Model:

```
class MyCustomModel
{
    public String Company_Name { get; set; } //<-What do I do here? 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried added this attribute to the `Company_Name` property: `[Column("Company Name")]`?

Comment: In the model? @DavidG

Comment: Yes, on the property in your model.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that ill try it now @DavidG

Comment: @Ellery Did that work?